# Relationship between velocity and time

Tags: calculus, kinematics

Is it true that the definite integral of $\dfrac1{v(x)}$ with respect to $x$ equals the time, where $v(x)$ is velocity as a function of distance?

I intuitively think that’s true because if you take a small distance $\mathrm dx$ where the velocity remains constant, the time spent equals $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{v(x)}$. Then, the total time would be the integral of that from the value of $x$ to another.

Comment: What is $x$? A time? A distance? What are the bounds of the integral?

Comment: @ericw31415 a distance, as $v(x)$ is velocity as a function of distance

Comment: Please explain what is $x$, $v(x)$  and the integral you are trying to calculate to make the question clear.

Answer (score 0):

We know that
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  x = f(t) \hfill \cr 
  dx = {{df(t)} \over {dt}}dt = v(t)dt \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Now, if $f(t)$ is invertible, or for each time interval in which it is , we can write
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  t = f^{\,\left( { - 1} \right)} (x) \hfill \cr 
  dt = {{df^{\,\left( { - 1} \right)} (x)} \over {dx}}dx =  \hfill \cr 
  {{df^{\,\left( { - 1} \right)} (x)} \over {dx}}{{df(t)} \over {dt}}dt = {{df^{\,\left( { - 1} \right)} (x)} \over {dx}}v(f^{\,\left( { - 1} \right)} (x))dt \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
which means that it must be
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  {{df^{\,\left( { - 1} \right)} (x)} \over {dx}}{{df(t)} \over {dt}} = 1 \hfill \cr 
  {{df^{\,\left( { - 1} \right)} (x)} \over {dx}}v(f^{\,\left( { - 1} \right)} (x)) = 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

You can conclude by yourself that your intuition is true.